# Can't execute update function in database

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a little struggle with my update function - it constantly gives me an annoying error which I'm not sure how to solve.

Basically, what I want to achieve is to get data from entry widgets, and then, call the update method and pass data from the entry widgets to the database.

*View*

```
self.update_employee_data = tk.Button(self.edit_employee_frame, text="Update", command=self.update_data)

    def update_data(self):

    if len(self.edit_employee_name.get() and self.edit_employee_surname.get() and
           self.edit_employee_position.get()) == 0:
        messagebox.showwarning("Missing Values", "Fill empty entries")
    elif (self.edit_employee_age.get() and self.edit_employee_salary.get()) < 1:
        messagebox.showwarning("Missing Values", "Fill empty entries")
    else:
        self.controller.update_employee_data(self.edit_employee_name, self.edit_employee_surname,
                                             self.edit_employee_age, self.edit_employee_position,
                                             self.edit_employee_salary, self.index)
    self.edit_employee_frame.grid_forget()
    self.main_frame.grid()
```

*Controller*

```
    def update_employee_data(self, name, surname, age, position, salary, id):
     self.model.update_employee_data(name, surname, age, position, salary, id)
```

*Model*

```
    def update_employee_data(self, name, surname, age, position, salary, id):
    connection = sqlite3.connect("employees_database.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""
        UPDATE employees 
        SET name = ? , surname = ?, age = ?, position = ?, salary = ? WHERE ID = ?
         """, (name, surname, age, position, salary, id,))

    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
```

*Error*

```
    cursor.execute("""
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

*Types of variables that I using for adding/deleting/reading data from employee table (I just have a struggle with update somehow)*

```
    name
<tkinter.StringVar object at 0x000001F53E214730> <class 'tkinter.StringVar'>

surname
<tkinter.StringVar object at 0x000001F53E2147F0> <class 'tkinter.StringVar'>

age
<tkinter.IntVar object at 0x000001F53E2148B0> <class 'tkinter.IntVar'>

position
<tkinter.StringVar object at 0x000001F53E214970> <class 'tkinter.StringVar'>

salary
<tkinter.IntVar object at 0x000001F53E214A30> <class 'tkinter.IntVar'>

id
1 <class 'int'>
```

Comment: Post the error that you get.

Comment: sorry, forgot about it. It's in the question.

Answer (score -1):

The error means that (at least) the first parameter (`name`) is not a supported type for bound parameters, like strings or integers.

It looks like you are calling the function with `self.edit_employee_name`, which does not seem to be a `String`, as it has a `get()` method, maybe a TK object ?

You should convert these objects to String.

Comment: They are Tk variables. I'll change them in a moment and see what will happen

Comment: So I've tried to play with it a bit, and I think there's not much difference between tk string, and "normal" string (ofc. I can be wrong though). I can read data, add, and delete using same variables, but I can't update with it. I don't know what should I think about it. I'll post types of all variables in my question.

Comment: I'm not sure a `tkinter.StringVar` can be bound, what happen if you convert them to string e.g.  `cursor.execute(... """, (str(name), ...`

Comment: I have solved it. Instead of saving data into vars, I just use getters from entry widgets.